# Getting an error "invalid use of non-static data member 'stu::n' "

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct stu {
      int n;

      stu(int _n = 0):n(_n) { }
      
      int add(int a, int b = n-1) {
            return a + b;
      }
};

int main() {
      stu obj = stu(5);
      cout << obj.add(10) << endl;
}
```

The compiler shows the message " invalid use of
non-static data member 'stu::n' ".
What is wrong with this code. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: `int b = n-1` is invalid default argument, as explained in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use default arguments this way. Consider writing two separate functions:

```
struct stu {
    int n;

    int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    int add(int a) { return a + n - 1; }
}
```